# python based server client for dynamic calculater

Tags: python, sockets, client-server

i created a python based client for netcat server which runs on port 20122 ,which runs a service for a game (dynamic calculator) it produce random mathematical expression (1+34+9+0=?) but due to time restriction the connection will terminate automatically so it have to replay quickly so i created a socket program on python which will store the out from server on string and this computer calculate and feed back to server it self,.but i did so far and executed the connection sticks in " you are connected to game server" nothing else kindly help me to correct my code .

the client code

[My client code](http://pastebin.com/R7GKApY0)
`import socket`

`def netcat(replay):`
`s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)`
 `s.connect(('192.168.56.101', 20055))`

`s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)`
`rec_data = []`
`while 1:`
`data=s.recv(1024)`
`exp=str(data)`
`replay = input(str(exp))`
`print replay`
`if not data:`
`break`
`rec_data.append(data)`
`return rec_data`
`s.sendall(replay)`

`if __name__ == '__main__':`
`replay = ''`
`recved = netcat(replay)`
`print recved[1]`

any one can tell me how i can extract mathematical expression only from data and execute it

thanks in advance

Comment: please include your code inline in the text of your question

Comment: i made a hyper link to it

Answer (score 0):

The `s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)` immediately after the `s.connect()` is out of place, since you want to `s.sendall()` later.